# Code does not recognize Listbox when I tried to fill it with array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, fill

Hi I am trying to fill a simple ListBox with array. The code that I have; it throws this error

Error 1   The name 'myArrayList' does not exist in the current context

```
public class Class1
{
    public void FillArray()
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 1000;
        int[] testArray = new int[1000];
        Random randNumber = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < testArray.Length; i++)
        {
            testArray[i] = randNumber.Next(min, max);  
        }
        foreach (int value in testArray)
        {
            myArrayList.ItemSource = testArray;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define your `myArrayList` ?

Comment: `Class1` is not the `Form`, so you need to move this method to your form class or find a way to pass the `ListBox` to this method, f.e. via method porameter.

Comment: You don't declare myArratList in your class

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Have you tried copying your `FillArray` method into your code-behind on `Form1` and try again?